# Scrollbar refuses to be hidden on IE / Firefox

Tags: html, css

[The traditional fix for this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/qqPcb/), in this instance - is not working for me. The vertical scroll bar persists. See below:

```
.outer {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
 overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

---

I need all the divs in my navigation. I've attempted to add the outer and inner overflow attribute at several levels of the parent/child div relations. None of which seem to be working. Here is my div tree:

```
<div>navbar-main
 <div>nav-items
  <div>list-items
   <div>ng-scope
    <div>ng-scope
     <div>sub-menu
```

---

There does not appear to be any conflicting code that would stop overflow from working.

Comment: what do you mean by "exception on IE / Firefox"

Comment: There's an exception to the rule where it works on Chrome. I revised the title, it was confusing.

Comment: Try adding white-space: nowrap to outer div or wrapper which wraps entire container. If its not working pls post entire html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the fiddle successfully works because the scrollbar of the inner `#scroller` div is being hidden by the outer `#wrapper` div. Notice that `#scroller` is 20px wider than `#wrapper`. Try setting widths for your divs, making the inner div wider than the outer, and see if that gives you the result you're looking for.

Comment: Your comment gave me some insight about how this works. After removing `width: 100%` from my `.list-items` div, I was able to add a hard set width to a child `<ul>`, resolving the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!